# An alternative to iPod nano 6g?

Tags: mp3, ipod-nano

I'm looking for a good, compact MP3 player that can also double as a pedometer (or at least as a part thereof). I wouldn't hesitate to buy a nano 6g if not for some of its 'features' that I'd rather avoid (expensive proprietary PC cable, iTunes required, and the general creepiness of a closed-source OS). However, looking at the competition, I haven't been able to find a single item that would impress me anywhere near nano 6g. Any suggestions? Thank you.

P.S. I understand that this may be not the most appropriate place to ask this question, given my requirements that must seem unusual for an Apple fan, but I don't really know of a more suitable forum.

Comment: How nice looking are you looking for? Checking mp3 pedometer -apple in google shopping brings some fugly but supposedly functional results.

Comment: I'm closing this for two reasons: 1) As per our FAQs, 'let's go shopping' questions aren't allowed. 2) This isn't about Apple hardware or software, it's about some other hardware to use instead.